# Java / Spring - Securing a Parameter ( Pathvariable )

Tags: java, string, spring, security

Is there a common way to secure a pathvariable?

```
@RequestMapping("/image/{id}")
public String getArticleImageUrl(@PathVariable String id) {

....
```

I mean remove unusual content e.g. javascript or other security issue related things to prevent "hacking" or abusive use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is secure depends on what you want to use the input for. Bottom line: You should take the same care with these kinds of parameters as any other parameter you would accept from the outside into the system, e.g.:

- Take appropriate action to prevent SQL injection (i.e. PreparedStatements)
- Take care when rendering stuff on your web site that was received as user input (i.e. make sure to HTML encode stuff - most frameworks would take care of this for you).
- etc.

"Washing" the input from unwanted characters is possible but, as always: tricky and depending on what the data will be used for.

Comment: Good hint. But in my case the regex is okay. I only accept alphanumeric input.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm.
I used a regex to check if this String is alphanumeric. ( `^[\\pL\\pN]+$` )
Should be enough.